# Hazelcast error - unable to store entries where MapStoreConfig is missing

Tags: java, hazelcast

I am facing below exception while upgrading hazelcast from 3.12 to 5.x and using MapStoreConfig to load data from DB. However for some of entities, this MapStoreConfig is null as I am using hazelcast to distribute the data, and facing below error while storing entities specific to ones where MapStoreConfig is missing . The code is working fine in 3.x. I would appreciate if any one can give any pointers for below issue:

```
Jan 29, 2024 10:31:00 AM com.hazelcast.internal.partition.impl.PartitionStateManager
INFO: [5.3.6] Initializing cluster partition table arrangement...
Jan 29, 2024 10:31:00 AM com.hazelcast.map.impl.operation.SetOperation
SEVERE:  [5.3.6] null
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.hazelcast.map.impl.operation.MapOperation.beforeRun(MapOperation.java:125)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.OperationRunnerImpl.run(OperationRunnerImpl.java:269)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.OperationRunnerImpl.run(OperationRunnerImpl.java:219)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.impl.OperationExecutorImpl.run(OperationExecutorImpl.java:454)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.impl.OperationExecutorImpl.runOrExecute(OperationExecutorImpl.java:511)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.Invocation.doInvokeLocal(Invocation.java:618)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.Invocation.doInvoke(Invocation.java:597)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.Invocation.invoke0(Invocation.java:558)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:241)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.InvocationBuilderImpl.invoke(InvocationBuilderImpl.java:71)
    at com.hazelcast.client.impl.protocol.task.AbstractPartitionMessageTask.processInternal(AbstractPartitionMessageTask.java:51)
    at com.hazelcast.client.impl.protocol.task.AbstractAsyncMessageTask.processMessage(AbstractAsyncMessageTask.java:71)
    at com.hazelcast.client.impl.protocol.task.AbstractMessageTask.initializeAndProcessMessage(AbstractMessageTask.java:169)
    at com.hazelcast.client.impl.protocol.task.AbstractMessageTask.run(AbstractMessageTask.java:132)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.OperationRunnerImpl.run(OperationRunnerImpl.java:198)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.impl.OperationThread.process(OperationThread.java:212)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.impl.OperationThread.process(OperationThread.java:146)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.impl.OperationThread.loop(OperationThread.java:134)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.impl.OperationThread.executeRun(OperationThread.java:115)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.util.executor.HazelcastManagedThread.run(HazelcastManagedThread.java:111)
```